# Fixing cracks in mortar shower pan before tiling

Tags: shower, tile, mortar

I am refinishing a shower and poured the shower pan using [CustomFloat Bedding Mortar](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-CustomFloat-50-lb-Bedding-Mortar-CFT50/100200705) several days ago. I mixed it according to the directions (3 Gallons of water per 50Lb bag).

Everything looked fine, however when walked on the pan yesterday the mortar cracked from the wall to the drain in a few places. No additional cracks seem to be developing but I don't think I should tile without first addressing the cracks. Is there anything I can do to repair the mortar before tiling or do I need to rip it out and try again?

-- EDIT --
Added picture
[image]

Comment: can you add pictures?   Nothing seems overly abnormal about your experience but maybe I am not getting it.

Comment: @DMoore Is a cracked top layer fine then? I was under the impression it would translate to cracks in the grout. I'll add pictures.

Comment: Mortar is for the formation of the bed.  There should be waterproofing of some sort before the thinset/tiles/grout is applied.  There is nothing you are going to do long term to make sure your mortar bed doesn't get cracks.  Yours may have shown up because it wasn't fully cured.  What are you using for waterproofing and can you zoom out on the picture (where is the drain?)?

Comment: @DMoore sorry about the poor quality picture. I'm not at home now and that's the only one I had on my phone. I did a layer of pre-slope, then placed the waterproof shower pan liner [link](https://www.tileshop.com/product/shower+pan+liner+tile+shower+pan+-+5+ft..do?sortby=ourPicks). This is the layer on top of the liner. I thought the next step was thinset/tile with no additional waterproofing.

Comment: If you are 100% confident in the waterproofing underneath then you are done.  If you are not you can throw on a couple of layers of redgard down which will also waterproof and will fill in the cracks.

Comment: My biggest issue would be did it crack from shrinkage or from movement? If it moved then the tile joints will crack. If it shrunk, the concrete may be weak from too much water added or poured too thin. I set my pans the same way the OP does with Redguard over all of it as a redundancy. I have never had the concrete bed crack but I add just enough water to get the concrete to set up. It is considered "dry pack". I place a minimum of 1 1/4" and if possible at least an 1 1/2" of sand mix high strength concrete.

Comment: @Jack It seems to me like it was probably poured too thin since I think the layer was only a little over 3/4". If it was due to shrinkage and not movement do I need to worry about cracked joints?

Comment: I would draw much concern over a pvc liner, concrete going in that thin. As mentioned before, I have never set it that thin. If it were me I would carefully pull it up, raise the drain as much as possible and still keep the drain stable, and repour the concrete with not so much water. I have set about 10 shower pans like this, so I do not have as much experience as some other may have. If they have set mud pans that thin and had it succeed, I would defer to those with more experience.

Comment: This is what I use    http://www.homedepot.com/p/SAKRETE-60-lb-Sand-Mix-65306217/100350697